# Highcharts partial display of series

Tags: highcharts

I am using a simple linechart. 
See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/w0do5vus/5/

I want to display just a partial width of the series(including the markers).

How can I achieve this? For the line I manage to hide it, but the markers are still visible.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
    });

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.clipRect.attr({
        width: 200
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe better is remove this points, or datalabels should leave?

Comment: If points are removed, datalabels should go away as well. 

Practically, based on the provided dataset I want to show just 50% of the chart. Is that possible? Or better asked, how can I display just 50% of the chart?

Comment: I would remove unnecessary points, and control visible range using `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`. Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w0do5vus/7/ Markers don't use clipRect, in compare to series line.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I will provide within a few days a more complex use-case, where playing around with the data from the series is not really wanted.